# implementing turtlebot bumper sensor

Tags: ros, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to subscribe to turtlebotSensorState to get bumps_wheeldrops. I think I've done everything right but in gazebo simulator when the robot hits an object it's not stopping.
below is my codes, any help is appreciated.
Also,it doesn't matter that I put the callback before main, does it?

---

```
#include turtlebot_node/TurtlebotSensorState.h>

#include ros/rate.h>

void callback01(const turtlebot_node::TurtlebotSensorState::ConstPtr& msg){
turtlebot_node::TurtlebotSensorState bumperState = msg->bumps_wheeldrops;
}
//this part goes to main:
ros::Subscriber sens_sub_ = n.subscribe<turtlebot_node::TurtlebotSensorState>("sensor_state", 1000, callback01);

ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
while (ros::ok()){
    if (bumperState !=0){
            publish (0,0);
    }else
            publish(angular_,linear_):
loop_rate.sleep();
ros::spin();
}
```

---

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42406/implementing-turtlebot-bumper-sensor/) by [Arash](https://answers.ros.org/users/3093/arash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ros::Subscriber sens_sub_ = n.subscribe<turtlebot_node::TurtlebotSensorState>("sensor_state", 1000, callback01);

this line should have /turtlebot_node/sensor_state

like this

ros::Subscriber sens_sub_ = n.subscribe<turtlebot_node::TurtlebotSensorState>("/turtlebot_node/sensor_state", 1000, callback01);

and as long as your main program can see bumperState

---

Originally posted by [teichel1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4190/teichel1/) with karma: 51 on 2013-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mai](https://answers.ros.org/users/20937/mai/) on 2014-12-03**:
Sorry! I run this example but there is below error. How can I do to fix this problem? thanks :(

/home/mai/catkin_ws/src/second/src/chan.cpp:1:49: fatal error: turtlebot_node/TurtlebotSensorState.h: No such file or directory
#include <turtlebot_node/TurtlebotSensorState.h>